# Vue.js Duplicate Content On Prerendered Pages

Tags: vue.js

When I display prerendered pages in production, the content appears on the page twice. It seems that instead of rehydrating the prerendered html elements returned from server, Vue.js renders the content again in the browser. So the page now contains the prerendered elements + duplicate elements created by Vue.js.

The prerendered pages contain attribute `data-server-rendered="true"` in the application div.

Did anyone else experience this problem?